# Does query by committee algorithm look like generalized binary search?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

Query by committee is an algorithm of active learning, as well as generalized binary search. But i do not sure how generalized binary search can be used in real-world problems? Is  query by committee algorithm just a simplification of generalized binary search algorithms?

Comment: please make your title all lowercase except for that initial "D" .. sorry, it's hard to read

Comment: I know i'm picky ... just a pet peeve of mine !!!

Comment: Sorry about that, i have corrected it!! :)